# custom flutter local package cannot load asset image

Tags: flutter

I am creating a package for my flutter app. Let's call it package1 which needs to load a page with some png/svg images:

the pubspec for package1 looks like:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/images/
```

I am using the local `package1` as follows:

```
  package1:
    path: ../package1
```

the following code throws error:

```
 SizedBox(
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    child: Image.asset("assets/icons/brightness.png"),
 ),
```

Error log:

```
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/icons/brightness.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#32d84(), name: "assets/icons/brightness.png", scale: 1.0)
```

I tried to load SVG image using the flutter_svg package but still the package cannot load the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to access your asset with the full package path:

```
Image.asset("packages/package_1/assets/icons/brightness.png"),
```

Ref: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/assets/assets-and-images

Comment: I'm not trying to load assets from package1 in my main app. I have some widgets in package1 that needs to access the assets

Comment: okay that worked. But how does that work when I am trying to access the assets from package1 for widgets inside package1? shouldn't widgets inside the package1 access the assets like: "assets/icons/brightness.png"?

Comment: No, you have to specify the full path even in the same package.